# How to convert m/dd/yyyy format to datetime format in informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Trying to convert `m/dd/yyyy` (for example: `5/22/2006`) value to datetime format in Informatica. I couldn't find suitable function to convert this format. I tried using below scenario but didn't work.

- Source Field datatype : String
- Source Field data : '5/22/2006'
- Condition: IIF(IS_DATE(Field1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE(Field1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), NULL)
- Target field Datatype: datetime
- Target field Data (Expected Data): '2006-05-22 00:00:00.000'

Can someone fine tune this condition to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can split based on / and check and then combine.

```
firstpart = SUBSTR(FIELD1,1, INSTR(FIELD1,'/'))
secondpart = SUBSTR(FIELD1, INSTR(FIELD1,'/')+1, INSTR(FIELD1,'/',2) - INSTR(FIELD1,'/')+1
lastpart = SUBSTR(FIELD1, INSTR(FIELD1,'/',2))

vfirstpart= IIF ( LENGTH(firstpart) = 1, '0'||firstpart, firstpart)
vsecondpart= IIF ( LENGTH(secondpart ) = 1, '0'||secondpart,secondpart)
vlastpart = IIF(LENGTH(lastpart )=2, '20'||lastpart ,lastpart )
vField1= vfirstpart||'/'||vsecondpart||'/'|| vlastpart `

Out_Final_date =  IIF(IS_DATE(vField1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE(vField1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Koushik. This condition will work but i have plenty of fields that i need to use the above condition which will make mapping complex

Comment: i would recoment to create a reusable mapping with an expression transformation or just expression transformation . Get the input as string, then do all above into it and generate 1 single output columns as date. repeat the calculations for multiple input/output fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function, it works properly. You have to check true/false condition.
If `IS_DATE` is true, then it returns 1, if false then 0

[image]

Comment: This perticular format is not listed in the Informatica acceptable formats. But still i gave a shot but it didnt work.

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/is_date.html

Comment: This has been converted to date. As you can see, the screen shot is from informatica application, which has been successfully converted to date